2D Vector Calculus Identity
I know that $\nabla\cdot{\textbf{v}} = 0$ and $\textbf{v}$ is 2 dimensional. I want to show that $\textbf{v}$ can be uniquely expressed as: $\textbf{v} = <f_y,-f_x,0>$ for some $f(x,y)$ (up to a constant).
I have that $\textbf{v} = \nabla \times \textbf{A}$ for any $\textbf{A}$. Writing this in component form I get $$\textbf{v} = \nabla \times \textbf{A} = <\partial_y A_z - \partial_z A_y, \partial_z A_x - \partial_x A_z, \partial_x A_y - \partial_y A_x>$$ Since $\textbf{v}$  is 2D I only know $\partial_x A_y - \partial_y A_x = 0$, the other components can be anything. I'm not sure how to proceed from here.

This de-tour through 3D is misleading. In 2D the theorems of Gauss and Green are equivalent. You can by flipping the components of $v$ and giving one of them a minus sign translate $\nabla\cdot v$ (divergence free) into a vector field that is rotation free. The integrals of that over a closed curve are all zero (assuming $v$ is defined in a simply connected region). What does a phsyicist know about line integrals that are independent of the path chosen?

okay, i feel like i follow most of this and can work it out, but shouldn't it work the way I'm doing it too? @KurtG.

It might be worthwhile to solve 2D first. In the 3D language this  leads to $\mathbf{A}$ that depends only on $x,y$ and not on $z$ and, as you said $\partial_xA_y-\partial_yA_x=0,.$ This will simplfy that $<\dots>$ expression in your post to an extend you would not have seen so directly by only working  in 3D I think.

Why is A dependent on x and y, and not on z? I think if I knew that, this would work. Its not clear to me that the vector field being confined to 2 dimensions means the vector potential is also confined to as many dimensions. @KurtG.

If you start in 2D the potential $f(x,y)$ depends only on $x$ and $y,.$ Then $A_z=f$ and all other components of $A$ are zero.
